# CSS background image on li:before not indenting properly

Tags: css

I have this before on a list item like so:

```
li.list-item-2::before {
    content: '' !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-image: url(/IMG_6331.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

However when I use a background image it doesn't indent the list item properly (see image)

[image]

But when I use content instead of background image like so:

```
ul.service-list-2 li:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f00c";
    margin: 0 5px 0 -15px;
    color: #4ba0e8;
}
```

the list item is indented properly (see image)

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share the full code of html and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check your second image properly then you will find that this is exactly the same as the first image, which has the image in Before, the only difference is the width of the element, the image you are using and the content by font-awesome has a different width and that's why you are finding this difference,

These have the same effect, let me show you,

[image]

as you can see in the image, content is going outside the pink box which means, you have the same condition in both the cases, but the difference is very less in the "content" case that's why you are not able to see it.

**Solution**

Make your before element, absolute and give the left side padding to LI, so that the image or your content will fit properly to the left of the LI.

```css
li.list-item-2 {
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 65px;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            list-style: none;
        }
        li.list-item-2::before {
            content: '' !important;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/Small_circle.svg/1200px-Small_circle.svg.png');
            background-size: cover;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li class="list-item-2">Test data</li>
        <li class="list-item-2">test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data </li>
        <li class="list-item-2">test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data test data </li>
        <li class="list-item-2">test data test data test data test data </li>
    </ul>
```

So in the case of font-awesome content, all you need to do is reduce the padding-left on LI, that's it.